# Application.EndRequest, MVC and .htm files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, httpapplication

I have the following code in my Global.asax:

```
void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpApplication application = sender as HttpApplication;
    HttpContext context = application.Context;
    string path = context.Request.Path;
    string contentType = context.Response.ContentType;

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Path: " + path);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ContentType:" + contentType);    
}
```

I have a Help folder at the root of the site (~/Help) that contains static .htm files. I notice that not all of these files are being run through EndRequest. Sometimes I see assets in the page being logged (e.g. .js files) but not the htm file itself. Sometimes they do get logged.

Why don't all of these files run through EndRequest and how can I ensure that they do?

Comment: That depends on how static content is handled in IIS and your AppPools pipeline mode, and some web config settings. In the case of static content that is a physical file sitting on disk and these configuration values, IIS might just serve the static content without getting ASP.NET involved at all.

Comment: I've set RouteExistingFiles to true and am testing that now. It seems to be working better with that set to true.

Comment: Another one is `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests` in your web.config should be set to true.

Comment: I checked that one already.

Comment: Is your App Pool in "Classic" pipeline mode, or "Integrated"?

Comment: RouteExistingFiles seems to actually have made it worse.

Comment: Is the server actually responding with HTTP 2XXs? Is the browser / client just caching the content and not even bothering to contact the server?

Comment: I've been clearing the cache and nada. I've turned off RouteExistingFiles as it was causing all of my regular files to 500. I've added a specific handler to web.config and am testing now.

Answer (score 0):

In the end my configuration is like this:

- AppPool pipeline: Integrated
- RouteExistingFiles: false (default)
- runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests: true

All of this was how it was when I wrote up this question. The thing I did different was to go into my web.config and manually add a handler under `<httpHandlers>`:

```
<add verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" path="*.htm" type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory" />
```

One thing that was throwing me off was that once the file had come down the browser was caching it and not re-requesting it (until I cleared the cache).